# java stream api - change Stream<List<Pair<A, B>>> to Pair<List<A>, List<B>>

Tags: java, java-stream

How do I change `Stream<List<Pair<A, B>>>` to `Pair<List<A>, List<B>>` ?
I have done it by:

1.using `collect(Collectors.toList())` to collect the `List<Pair<A, B>>` result

2.iterating the list result and adding `A`s and `B`s to two separate lists

3.creating a new `Pair<List<A>, List<B>>`

But I got really paranoid about **getting this done while still in the stream**. 
Need help. Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala edited. got confused by the <>s

Comment: Could you put your nonworking code so we can try to improve/fix it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. using `collect(Collectors.toList())` to collect the `List<Pair<A, B>>` result

You can write *custom* collector, use `Collector.of()` (in this example **javafx.util.Pair**):

```
  List<Pair<A, B>> pairs = // list of Pait
  Pair<List<A>,List<B>> pairOfLists = pairs.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collector.of(
                            //init accumulator
                            () -> new Pair<>(
                                     new ArrayList<>(),
                                     new ArrayList<>()
                            ), 
                            //processing each element
                            (pairOfLists, pair) -> {
                                pairOfLists.getKey().add(pair.getKey());
                                pairOfLists.getValue().add(pair.getValue());
                            },
                            //confluence of two accumulators in parallel execution
                            (pairOfLists1, pairOfLists2) ->{
                                pairOfLists1.getKey().addAll(pairOfLists2.getKey());
                                pairOfLists1.getValue()addAll(pairOfLists2.getValue());
                                return pairOfLists1;
                            }
                    )
            );
```

> Mind the existence of [the three-argument version of Stream.collect()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-), which makes the `Collector.of()` obsolete and the combiner simpler for such use cases.

```
  Pair<List<A>, List<Integer>> p2 = p.stream()
            .collect(
                    () -> new Pair<>(
                            new ArrayList<>(),
                            new ArrayList<>()
                    ),
                    (pairOfLists, pair) -> {
                        pairOfLists.getKey().add(pair.getKey());
                        pairOfLists.getValue().add(pair.getValue());
                    },
                    (pairOfLists1, pairOfLists2) -> {
                        pairOfLists1.getKey().addAll(pairOfLists2.getKey());
                        pairOfLists1.getValue().addAll(pairOfLists2.getValue());
                    }
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve wanted result within the Stream itself, you can do it using `reduce()`:

```
final Pair<List<A>, List<B>> result = stream
    .map(s -> {
      Pair<List<A>, List<B>> p = new Pair<>(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());
      p.getKey().add(s.getKey());
      p.getValue().add(s.getValue());
      return p; 
    })
    .reduce((pairA, pairB) -> {
      pairA.getKey().addAll(pairB.getKey());
      pairA.getValue().addAll(pairB.getValue());
      return pairA;
    })
    .get();
```

However, more elegant solution would be to iterate trough your `Stream` and fill both lists, create `Pair` at the end, like so:

```
    final Stream<Pair<A, B>> stream = // your stream

    final List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();

    stream.forEach(p -> {
        listA.add(p.getKey());
        listB.add(p.getValue());
    });

    final Pair<List<A>, List<B>> result = new Pair<>(listA, listB);
```

Depends on why you want to transform it into a `Pair` inside a Stream.

EDIT: Just note that using first example, you are creating a lot new object instances for every element in initial Stream. It is far from optimal solution. But if you want to achieve this inside a Stream, I don't see any other option.

Comment: OP wanted to create the pair while in the stream

Comment: A bit complicated as you mentioned but works I suppose

Comment: That's an abuse of `reduce`. Will break with parallel streams. I strongly recommend reading [the package documentation about Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction).

Answer (score 0):

This is the most straightforward solution, yet effective, I have found:

```
Pair<List<T1>, List<T2>> target = new Pair<>(
    pairStream.stream().map(i -> i.getT1()).collect(Collectors.toList()),
    pairStream.stream().map(i -> i.getT2()).collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

I assume the class Pair has a constructor `public Pair(T1 t1, T2 t2)`.

I am not aware of any solution being able to return the desired result using a single stream.